# Is it possible to use Lambdas like this in Ruby?

Tags: python, ruby, lambda, closures

Here is what I do quite often in Python:

```
simple_call = lambda name: extract(some[fairly][hidden], name)
result1 = simple_call('myname')
result2 = simple_call('yourname')
result3 = simple_call('hisname')
```

This is really handy if you have to extract some data from some complex data structure or some strange API repeatedly.

Is there a way to do the same thing in Ruby?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short answer: No. The closest thing is:

```
simple_call = lambda {|name| extract(some[:fairly][:hidden], name) }
result1 = simple_call.call("myname")
result2 = simple_call.call("yourname")
result3 = simple_call.call("hisname")
```

Why? Because parenthesis in Ruby are optional. Then, you need to tell ruby to call the method. For example, in Python you could do:

```
another_simple_call = simple_call
```

And you are assigning the lambda to `another_simple_call`. But in Ruby there would be no way to know if you are assigning or calling simple_call with zero arguments.

Comment: You're using about the most verbose code possible. For Ruby 1.9, I'd do: `simple_call = ->(name){ ... }; result1 = simple_call['byname']` which is almost exactly what the OP has, turning your "No." into a "Yes."

Comment: Didn't get your point, you can easily assign `labmda` in a simple assignment like `another_simple_call = simple_call`. Parenthesis for calling `lambda` (`[]` or `.call`) are not optional. Only object methods can be called without parenthesis.

Comment: @Phrogz Nice, I remember reading that once, but I haven't yet integrated it into my project.  Is this likely to become the preferred way to do lambdas?

Comment: Phrogz, point to the -> syntax. IMHO, the simple_call['byname'] is not consistent so I tend to forget about it.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, there is a way to do the same thing in Ruby. And it is in fact the same way (modulo the minor syntactic differences between Python and Ruby, of course):

```
simple_call = ->name { extract(some[fairly][hidden], name) }
result1 = simple_call.('myname')
result2 = simple_call.('yourname')
result3 = simple_call.('hisname')
```

Answer (score 5):

An equivalent in Ruby would be

```
a = Proc.new{|name| do_something_with(name) }

a.call("anyname")
```

Answer (score 4):

One other way that I do stuff like this is to try to use blocks and a map command rather than lambdas.

So do something like:

```
result1, result2, result3 = %w(myname yourname hisname).map {|name|
    extract(some[fairly][hidden], name)
}
```

I find it reads a little better.

Comment: interesting solution. Not immediately applicable in my case, but very interesting! Thank you!

Comment: +1. Typically either a block will do, or else an actual method is the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

Yep:

```
arbitrary_data_structure = {
  :foo => {
    :bar => "1",
    :baz => "2",    
  }
}

extract_process = lambda { |x| arbitrary_data_structure[:foo][x] }

puts extract_process.call(:bar) # => "1"
puts extract_process.call(:baz) # => "2"
```